# Excel to pdf conversion in rails4 with libreoffice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, pdf-generation, libreoffice

In a rails 4 application,  how can I convert an excel spreadsheet file into pdf.

When I am trying to implement Excel to pdf the contents are listed in different pages if excel column size is large.

How to generate the pdf without moving data to next pages in pdf.

Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you basically have two options you can either implement this yourself and use a CSV gem/library ([default CSV](https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-ruby-csv-library-part/), [faster CSV](https://github.com/JEG2/faster_csv), or [smarter CSV](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv)) assuming that by "excel" a CSV is acceptable. If a CSV is not acceptible you can use the [axlsx gem](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails) instead. Then for pdf conversion you can use something like [prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn). If you decide to build this yourself follow these steps.

1. Create a controller that will handle Reports, I suggest using the `rails g controller report upload generate_table show generate_pdf` generator to create a controller and a view for the upload process
2. Create a file upload form in the upload view.
3. On submit you will send the file to the generate action processing with one of the CSV or excel gems
4. Once processed your end product should be an array or hash (as an instance variable) and you can send that to the show action
5. In the show view you will iterate of that hash/array and incapsulate the contents in a html table.
6. On the show view you should have a button that will send that same hash/array to the `generate_pdf` controller action where you will use `prawn` to create a pdf, you can use something like [send_data](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data) to the send the completed pdf file back to the user.

This is roughly how you could go about it less the low level details. Now if you wanted to use an out of the box solution you could use something like [Ruport](https://github.com/ruport/ruport). Ruport will handle most of the heavy lifting for you the only thing is you need to have your models and associations set up to use it the way it is designed, and that may not be an option for you.